# Explain why the following functions f and g are not equal

Tags: functions

This is a question posed in one my classes, and I am stumped. I feel that there is a subtlety that I am missing. As far as I can tell, the domain and codomain are identical for $f(x)$ and $g(x)$.

The question is to explain why these two are not equal, $f(x) = x − 2$, and $g(x) = (x^2 − 4)/(x + 2)$ (The variable $x$ ranges over real numbers.)

Thanks for the help!

Comment: g is not defined at $x=-2$

Comment: please use proper tagging, this has nothing to do with functional analysis.

Comment: Division by zero?

Comment: The domains are *not* equal.  $x = -2$ is valid point in the domain of $f$ but is *not* a valid point in the domain of $g$.  The functions aren't equal because they have different domains.  That's all there is to it.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Because these two functions don’t share the same domain.

Recall: Two functions are equal if and only if they have the same value at the same point and the same domain.

Comment: The converse of that statement is not true in general. $f(x)=x^2$ and $g(x)=|x|$ have the same image and domain, but these functions are not equal.

Comment: Edited $\quad\quad$

Comment: I think you shoud say 'value at the same point', not 'image'. You can take an image of a set, but value at a point. This is what KronZ refered to when he said that the images of functions $x^2$ and $|x|$ are the same.

Comment: @AdamLatosiński You’re right. I am a french native, and in french we usually use ‘image’.